# Excel VBA - Error '1004' when inserting value in last non empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I get Run-time error '1004'

> Application-defined or object-defined error

when i'm try to insert value starting from B19.

Below are the code:

```
Private Sub test()

If Application.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(2), Range("A5").Value) Then
    MsgBox "Already taken, try another username"
Else
    MsgBox "Done"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B19" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Range("A5").Value

End If

End Sub
```

The purpose of this code is to insert value from A5 to last non empty row starting from B19.

Comment: Your address:  `("B19" & Rows.Count)`  resolves to `B191048576`, which is an illegal address.  Hence the error.  The last empty cell in column B will be returned by `cells(rows.Count,"B").end(xlup).offset(1,0)` **BUT** you will have to specifically test for `B19` not being empty, if you want to start at `B19`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this:

```
Private Sub main()
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("B19:B" & WorksheetFunction.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, 19))
            If Application.CountIf(.Cells, .Parent.Range("A5").Value) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "Already taken, try another username"
            Else
                .Cells(.Rows.Count + IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells(.Rows.Count)), 0, 1)).Value = .Parent.Range("A5").Value
                MsgBox "Done"
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: i implement the code by modify it as below:

change "B19:B" to "L19:L" and A5 to B24. However it start to key in from row 47.

Comment: since you change reference column from "B" (i.e. column index 2) to "L" (i.e. column index 12) you also have to change `...Cells(.Rows.Count, 2)...` to `...Cells(.Rows.Count, 12)...`

Answer (score 0):

2 comments:

First: `CountIf` returns a number, so if there is atleast one Count, you should check if the result is > 0 (not if `True`).

Second: Getting to the last row with data after Range("B19"), you need to use `.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)`.

Try the code below:

```
Private Sub test()

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.CountIf(.Columns(2), .Range("A5").Value) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Already taken, try another username"
    Else
        If .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row < 19 Then ' <-- check if the last row in Column B is less than 19
            .Range("B19").Value = .Range("A5").Value
        Else
            .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("A5").Value
        End If

        MsgBox "Done"           
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This would be wrong, if there is no value in column B. In this case the OP wants the value to be written in B19.

Comment: I'm not sure you are right, as I understood it most likely he has data up tp "B19", that's why he wants to find the last row with data (after "B19"), and put "A5" in the first empty row below it (I might be wrong - the PO will explain better)

Comment: You can still start from B19, independently whether he has data before or not.

Comment: A little remark, although the OP did it that way, but I think it would be more logical to `msgbox "done"` *after* the success of the operation.

Comment: Data in A5 is inserted by using userform box. Thats a different story. But everytime data inserted in A5, the code above need to check whether the data is exist in column B. if no, insert the value in column B. However i need to start from B19.

Comment: @Jeeva  so try the code above and see if it's fits ur needs

Comment: @ShaiRado..no. it is not fit my requirement.

Comment: @ShaiRado because it start from B2. I want it start from B19

Comment: @Jeeva try now, copy the entire edited code (instead of my previous one) and see if it works like u wanted